# Can anyone review this page in IE 6/7/8 and tell me why it is breaking so badly?

Tags: html, internet-explorer

http://iamwhitebox.com/staging/arkitek/index.php#press.htm

I think its just a float/margin bug but I haven't been able to pinpoint it

??

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' />
    <title>Arkitek Studios | Press</title> 
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='css/core.css' />
<style>
    article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, footer, header,
    hgroup, menu, nav, section { display: block; }
    </style> 
<!--[if IE]>
      <script src='http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js'></script>
    <![endif]-->
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js'></script> <script type='text/javascript' src='js/dynamicpage.js'></script> 
</head>
<body>
<?php
    include_once 'includes/header.inc';
?>
<div id='guts'>
    <section id='page'>
        <div class='leftfloat logoPress'></div>     
        <article class='rightfloat'>
            <img style='padding-top:12px;' src='img/img1.jpg' alt='#'>
        </article>
    <div style='padding-top:75px;'>
        <article style='width:275px;' class='leftfloat'>
            <nav id='press'>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href='#' alt=''>MISSION</a></li>
                    <li><a href='#' alt=''>CURRENT NEWS</a></li>
                    <li><a href='#' alt=''>PRESS RELEASES</a></li>
                    <li><a href='#' alt=''>STAFF BIOS</a></li>
                    <li><a href='#' alt=''>TESTIMONIALS</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </article>
        <article style='width:250px;' class='leftfloat'>
            <p>To be a world-class design resource 
            that contributes to the advancement 
            of understanding in  science and 
            technology.</p><br />
            <p>To skillfully blend education and 
            entertainment to create effective, 
            universal communications.</p><br />
            <p>To create accurate work that captivates, 
            educates and ignites the imagination of 
            people of all ages around the world.</p>
        </article>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
<?php
    include_once 'includes/footer.inc';
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: html5 and IE don't get along very well...at all.

Answer (score 0):

As commented by ScottE in your question, HTML5 and IE don't get along very well.

Using IE8 developer tool, one of the problem you can see is that the image is *below* your `article` tag, not within article tag as in other modern browser. This happens to all other `article` tags in your page as well.

[image]

Perhaps you should use `div` instead of `article`.